# Unsupported format or combination of formats OpenCV findcontours

Tags: java, opencv

I am new to Opencv. I am using it in java. Could you please tell me where I went wrong in the following coding? I always get the unsupported format error - "Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only) in cvStartFindContours".
Thanks in advance.

```
        Mat dst = new Mat();
        destination.convertTo(dst,CvType.CV_32SC1);
        List<MatOfPoint> points = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(dst, points, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_FLOODFILL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        Mat cImg = new Mat(dst.size(), dst.type());
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            Imgproc.drawContours(cImg, points, i, new Scalar(0, 255,0), -1);
        }
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("contour.jpg", cImg);
```

Comment: Convert the image to cv_8uc1 and then apply findcontours.

Comment: Thank you :) the error cleared but ended up getting some error in array.cpp..